# How to parse this string into tokens using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to parse the following string:

```
"{Host=pc@ip}{Encoder=EncoderName}{Date=2014_8_5}{Resolution=90X90}
{File=2014-8-5_11-50-50_189.jpeg}"
```

into five separate strings:

```
"{Host=pc@ip}"
"{Encoder=EncoderName}"
"{Date=2014_8_5}"
"{Resolution=90X90}"
"{File=2014-8-5_11-50-50_189.jpeg}"
```

Using a regular expression.

Comment: MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message.MessageLabel, "{.+=.+}");

Comment: What are the "fixed" parts of the string and what are the ones that are changing? What are the rules for those changing parts?

Comment: The fixed parts are {=}{=}...{=} and the changing parts is the text inside.

Comment: Not so hard - `{[^}]*}`. And use Regex.Matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
\{([^\}]*)\}
```

Of course, you'll have to worry about a few things, like if you have nested braces, but this [works on the string you gave us](http://regexr.com/3998b). I also added in the parentheses, so you should be able to use groups in your matches if you want. It isn't necessary, but I imagine your curly braces will just get in the way of whatever further parsing you do.